# Alternative to Delete Polygons And Extend Lines of Production Mapping?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, generalization

Maybe someone knows an alternative for the [Delete Polygons And Extend Lines (Production Mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//010900000032000000) tool or a simple way to achieve the same result but without requiring a Production Mapping license?

Comment: What level of license do you have (Basic/Standard/Advanced)?

Comment: I'm using Advanced

Comment: If you want to avoid writing a Python script that would iterate your polygona and polyline feature classes, you might try playing first with the Aggregate Polygons/Simplify Polygon (Cartography toolbox) to get rid of small polygons (check how large your polygons are) and then Integrate (Data Management toolbox) to connect the end vertices of the rivers that are closer than some threshold. Another crazy idea is to collapse lakes into lines first with Polygon to Line and then Integrate again on this spaghetti.

Comment: @mik Ok no problem. To be honest I was just really interested in the problem. I'll delete the answer and best of luck with your work.

Comment: @mik I'm just curious if you ever found a solution to this problem and if so if you could share it?

Comment: I think your question could be improved by the inclusion of a picture that illustrates what that Production Mapping tool does within your question, and also to specify whether or not you are looking for an ArcPy solution.